# Approximately how many people uses Ubuntu and linux in general?

Tags: users, downloads

It really interest me one thing. Approximately how many people uses Ubuntu and linux in general? Since it has cc 1,50% market share. How much downloads Ubuntu has?

Comment: The Debian Installer has an option that asks if the user wants to publish their package lists every week. It is called the popularity-contest, and it is used to see what packages should go on the first install disk. Debian probably counts the number of users who send information (although many users don't use this). I'll try to see if Debian publishes the numbers.